Libc6:amd64 broken package
So idk what happened, I think I stopped an update midway but now I'm stuck with my packages not updating anything due to libc6. Full message is
dpkg:error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess was killed by signal (Segmentation fault), core dumped
Errors were encountered while processing:
libc6:amd64 

Any tips on how to fix? I've done the bunch of

sudo apt-get purge libc6:amd64
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get remove --purge libc6:amd64

And probably a few more I just forgot lol.

Wow, segfault? I'd start with evaluating the hardware health: test memory and cpu as a minimum. Also, what system is this, ubuntu what?
